# Windows 10 machine without a monitor. Display options?

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to connect a laptop to a Windows desktop, with no connected monitor, and use the screen of the laptop as the desktop's monitor?

Comment: Truly, monitors are inexpensive - certainly more so than a new high end gaming laptop. Just get a monitor for the desktop.

Comment: @John I only need the display for 2-3 days which is why I'm looking for a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may vary, depending on the use you mean to have:

1. You need to connect the desktop and laptop only once, and leave the system as that, or
2. You also use the laptop on its own sometimes. This is a more complex scenario. Case 1, with repeated reboots, may become similar to this case 2.

You have a few options:

1. Connect a software for sharing screen/control (e.g., TeamViewer, VNC), with the desktop as a server and the laptop as a client. Then whatever you do on the desktop will be seen in TeamViewer on the laptop.
   The connection goes through the network, so it *might* be not completely smooth.
   You would need (some of this applies to other options as well):

   1.1. A monitor available for the initial setup of the desktop.

   1.2. To confirm you can allow TeamViewer on the desktop to automatically allow connections from the client (so you don't need to take any action on the desktop each time you connect).

   1.3. To have both devices connected to the network.
2. Use [SpaceDesk](https://spacedesk.net/).
3. Use your laptop as a [wireless display](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-connect-to-a-wireless-display-in-windows-10), with *Project to this PC*. Only with Win 10 (given the tag, I assume this is your case).
4. [Mess with the hardware](https://www.instructables.com/Old-laptop-screen-into-Monitor/) (for the more venturous). See also [this](https://hackernoon.com/https-medium-com-akshaykore-diy-monitor-410ac3bbb6b9).

**Related**:

1. https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-a-laptop-as-a-primary-monitor-for-my-CPU/answer/Kelly-Curry-31
2. https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-use-your-laptop-as-a-monitor
3. https://techguided.com/how-to-use-a-laptop-as-a-monitor/
4. https://store.hp.com/us/en/tech-takes/how-do-I-use-laptop-as-monitor
5. https://freedom251.com/use-laptop-as-a-monitor/
6. https://hardforum.com/threads/can-i-use-a-laptop-as-the-primary-display-for-a-desktop-system.1618229/
7. https://basiccomputertips.com/can-you-use-a-laptop-as-a-monitor/

Comment: It is good if you post feedback as an EDIT to the OP, on what solution finally worked for you, with brief details.
That will possibly help others, and this builds a useful community for all of us.